# Unresolved import warnings

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm just getting started with Visual Studio Code.  After opening a folder with Python scripts, those that import scripts in the same folder are marked `Import xxx could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)`.  However, the imports exist and the code runs without errors.  Imports of library modules are not marked as errors.

Setting `Python > Analysis: Extra Paths` to `.` did not help.

[Problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKDVu.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide your folder structure? And tell us what level of folder you have opened in vscode. [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It's just a single folder containing a bunch of independent python scripts plus a couple of modules included by a few of them.  I just ran VSCode, opened the folder, and set the path to python.exe when prompted.

Comment: If all python scripts are in one folder and open this folder in vscode. There are no import errors.

Comment: Problem is not solved.  I've been away and haven't had time to look into this further.

Comment: See the updated answer if needed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell Visual Studio Code the path to python for your project. Your python binary is probably located inside your virtual environment. Click Settings, Workspace and search for Python default interpreter path and paste in the relevant path.

You can determine the path after activating your virtual environment in a terminal using one of the following commands.

Windows command:

```
where.exe python
```

Linux command:

```
type python
```

Visual Studio Code will save this information in a settings.json file in the .vscode folder.

Comment: This did not fix the problem.  `where.exe` python returns ...`\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe`, which is a zero-length file.  It's actually `C:\tools\Anaconda3\python.exe`. 

There's no `Users\<user>\.vscode\settings.json` file.

`Run` messages include `UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.`

I've been using Eclipse, which has become bloated, but it looks like switching to VSCode is going to be a research project.

Comment: Sounds like you are not using a Python virtual environment. The settings.json gets created when you set the default interpreter path as described.

Comment: I did find a `settings.json` file in `.vscode` the folder I opened that contains the python scripts and included modules:

{
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "."
    ],
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\\tools\\Anaconda3\\python.exe"
}

These settings appear to be correct, yet the imports are still marked as problems.

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding the following configuration in the **settings.json** file

```json
    "python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
    "reportMissingImports": "none",
    },
```

---

---

If your script file is in the same folder as the module files you import, it will never fail. So please check your settings (user setting and workspace setting) if there is any setting that is causing the error.

[image]

***Additional solutions:***

Add the following configuration in **settings.json**:

```json
// Change the path to your own folder path
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\euler",
    ]
```

Comment: Without the suggested setting, e.g. 6 problems are reported in a script, 2 `reportMissingImports` and 4 `reportUndefinedVariable` for variables in the imported modules.  With the suggested setting, only the 4 `reportUndefinedVariable` problems are reported and imports that actually are missing are ignored.

Comment: Please show your folder structure and your message, error code section. My answer is just based on your simple error message. If you can't provide more effective information, how can we help you solve the problem?

Comment: The error message I see in `PROBLEMS` is in my original post.  Is there somewhere else I should look?  There's just a single folder, no structure, as noted in a comment on my original post.

Comment: Please show, all error messages, open file interface. Can you show screenshots?

Comment: Screenshot of Problems added to original post.

Comment: Adding:
`{
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "\\NAS0\home\git\Keith\euler"
    ],
}`
to `\\NAS0\home\git\Keith\euler\.vscode\settings.json` did not fix the problem.  Shouldn't Pylance use the same environment as the python run time by default?

Comment: Yes. So as you can see this works without any issues on my machine (no extra settings). Final advice: If you have time, check your settings, or empty your settings.json file. If the error persists, I'm afraid you can only try reinstalling the python extension and VS code.

Answer (score 0):

The false `Import xxx could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)` problems were occurring with Visual Studio Code and the Python VSCode Extension installed by Chocolatey.

1. Uninstall both
2. Delete the `.vscode` folder
3. Reinstall the Visual Studio Code
4. And instead, installing the "Pylance VSCode Extension" fixed this issue.